# Generating all possible rankings when merging sorted lists with rank instead of raw score information per element

Tags: combinatorics, sorting

Let $\{e_1, e_2, ..., e_n\}$ be the set of elements.
Let $\{s_1(e_1), s_1(e_2), ..., s_1(e_n)\}$, $\{s_2(e_1), s_2(e_2), ..., s_2(e_n)\}$ be the scores of elements after applying two ranking functions $s_1$, $s_2$.
Let $\{w\cdot s_1(e_1) + (1-w)\cdot s_2(e_1), w\cdot s_1(e_2) + (1-w)\cdot s_2(e_2), ..., w\cdot s_1(e_n) + (1-w)\cdot s_2(e_n)\}$, $w\in[0, 1]$, be the final scores after the combination of individual scores. I am interested in the set of all potential rankings of the elements that can be constructed this way (considering the final scores above for all $w\in[0,1]$). Can I generate the same set of final rankings when ignoring the raw scores after the application of functions $s_1$, $s_2$ and relying on linear combination of the corresponding ranks per list instead? I.e. using $\{v\cdot r_1(s_1(e_1))) + (1-v)\cdot r_2(s_2(e_1)), v\cdot r_1(s_1(e_2)) + (1-v)\cdot r_2(s_2(e_2)), ..., v\cdot r_1(s_1(e_n)) + (1-v)\cdot r_2(s_2(e_n))\}$, $v\in[0, 1]$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the ranks per list according to scorings $s_1$ and $s_2$.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What do you mean by “using linear combinations of elements score”?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If all we know is that $a_1>a_2>\cdots >a_n$ and $b_1>b_2>\cdots>b_m$ then  there are $\binom {n+m}n$ ways to sort them which preserve the ordering within the $a's$ and $b's$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please [edit] the question to show us some examples of the lists you are merging and concatenating with linear combinations of scores.

Comment: As you can see from the comments, nobody can sort out what you are asking.  Please edit for clarity.  A natural idea might be to include a clear, explicit example of the sort of thing you are talking about.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Don't leave critical information for the comments.  And, again, I'd suggest including a clear, explicit example of the sort of thing you have in mind.  Presumably, if the list of elements is very short, you can just write eveything out, yes?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Better, but still unclear (to me). Can you [edit] to show us some numerical examples for, say, $n=3$. Then there are six possible orderings.

Comment: Post edit:  this is still not clear.  Say you have two students $A,B$ and that there were two tests.  If all I know is that $A$ did better than $B$ on the first and $B$ did better than $A$ on the second, I have no way to predict who did better if you averaged the scores.  How could I?  But perhaps you meant something else, without an example it's just guesswork.

Comment: the question is more if I can prove that there exists a coefficient for the latter case (the more constrained one) that I can use in order to reproduce the ranking per the former case.

Comment: You can answer this one yourself.  Just generate random scoring functions and see if they obey this property. (I'd guess not.)